# Flexbox : Child item not occupying 100% of parent,occupies only its minimum width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent container with flex display and width set as 100%, its child element (sub container) is set to occupy max-width 25%.

Button on sub container is assigned with minimum width and max width as below. Buttons tend not to occupy 100% of sub container even if its max width is set as 100%.

I have tried adding flex-items and flex self stretch, but they dont not to occupy 100% of width.

Code and Style on Fiddle link:https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-field-9ckst
When screen is widened they don't appear to occupy 100% of its parent thats 25% of the entire screen. I am trying to make button to occupy entire 25% of screen at any time.Any suggestions is appreciated.

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.subcontainer {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.label {
  align-content: left;
}

.buttonStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <button class="buttonStyle">
          <div class="label">label1</div>
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <button class="buttonStyle">
             <div class="label">label2</div>
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <button class="buttonStyle">
          <div class="label">label3</div>
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the min-width and max-width, if you want a full length button.

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.subcontainer {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.label {
  align-content: left;
}

.buttonStyle {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <button class="buttonStyle">
      <div class="label">label1</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <button class="buttonStyle">
      <div class="label">label2</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <button class="buttonStyle">
      <div class="label">label3</div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to change `class` to `className` when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste).

Answer (score 1):

DEMO link:https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-leavitt-bqccz

Remove flex:1; from .subcontainer class and change .subcontainer class max-width:100% to min-width:100%;.

```
.subcontainer {
  align-items: stretch;
  min-width: 25%;
}
```

change .buttonStyle class max-width:100% to width:100%.

```
.buttonStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try the below given css the child elements occupies 25% width:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.subcontainer {
  align-items: stretch;
  min-width: 25%;
}

.label {
  align-content: left;
  /* display: flex; */
}
.buttonStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```